# C# audio directory issue

Tags: audio, c#

Alright, I'm developing a speech recognition system which is working completely fine, I've had no problems with it up until now. And yes i did google search it and look to see if the question had already been answered, but nothing turned up.

What I did was save some text-to-speech lines and put them into the program, it worked fine up until about the 5th audio file, I ran it to try and test if it worked and the program crashed with this error:

```
NotSupportedException: The given path's format is not supported
```

which is weird because for every other audio file it worked, the code looks like this :

```
System.Media.SoundPlayer player8 = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"‪C:\Users\user\Desktop\JMAS LINE\15.wav");player8.Play();
```

It's strange because only specific ones work and don't work
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: So did you verify with some other player (like VLC) that the file is indeed okay?

Comment: (1) You say, “it worked fine up until about the 5th audio file”, and I’m not sure what you mean.  Do you mean that some files consistently work and some files consistently don’t work (this is what you seem to be saying in the next paragraph), or are you saying that, after you have successfully processed four files, the next one fails, *no matter which one it is?*  (2) I’m intrigued by the message ‘‘The given ***path's*** format is not supported’’.  Is it possibly an issue with the files’ ***names**?*  Try taking one file that works and one that doesn’t, and renaming them to each other’s names.

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (3) It might help if you told us something about your environment — what operating system; what compiler and software development environment, etc. … … … … … … …  … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  P.S. One can make the argument that this question is about getting system services to work, and about file formats, and therefore it is on-topic for Super User.  However, some people will make the argument that the question is about programming, and therefore it is off-topic for Super User and belongs on [SO]. If you don’t get a satisfactory answer here after a couple of days, I suggest that you flag it for moderator attention and ask to have it migrated to Stack Overflow.  Please do *not* simply re-ask the question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: The exception you got says "_The given path's format is not supported_". The "_given path_" here means simply the "given audio file". Thus, the error in other words: "_The given audio files's format is not supported_". Now, i don't know the limitations of System.Media.SoundPlayer, but clearly it does not accept that particular audio file (maybe it is because the WAV file in question is 32 bit, or has an uncommon channel number, or whatever; i am just speculating here about possible SoundPlayer limitations; perhaps playback of this WAV would demand a codec that's not installed on your machine)